# Serialize Django User in template: Object of type Group is not JSON serializable

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I've a Django CBV DetailView that has an embedded Vue app.

In the view, I get some of the data and pass it to the template so Vue can access it appropriately.

The view data looks like this:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["summative"] = get_object_or_404(
            Summative, id=self.kwargs["summative_id"]
        )
        context["json_requestor"] = model_to_dict(self.request.user)
        context["json_evaluation"] = model_to_dict(self.object)
        return context
```

In the template I add it like this:

```
    {{ json_requestor|json_script:"requestor-data" }}
    {{ json_evaluation|json_script:"evaluation-data" }}
```

`json_evaluation` comes across fine. However the `json_requestor` is where the error pops up.

It gives this error: `Object of type Group is not JSON serializable`

Any thoughts on how to best fix this issue?

Comment: Can you show what `model_to_dict` is

Comment: That is a built-in method in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/forms/models/

Comment: Oh didn't know that. Thanks. TIL